# Elastic Search Date Histogram Bucket Count Filtering

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Is it possible to apply a filter to date histogram buckets ?
For example return only buckets that are below a certain value. I was looking to do it with scripts but dont know how to access buckets in script, so if anyone knows anything about that, it would be very very very helpful

Answer (score 2):

At this time you cannot filter the result of an aggregation.  This is something that the team is considering but is not in place.

See this issue:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8110

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. I was thinking it would be possible to do it with script field...